# Understanding HTTPS connection setup overhead

Tags: ajax, https

I'm building a web-based chat app which will need to make an AJAX request for every message sent or received. I'd like the data to be encrypted and am leaning towards running AJAX (with long-polling) over HTTPS.

However, since the frequency of requests here is a lot higher than with basic web browsing, I'd like to get a better understanding of the overhead (network usage, time, server CPU, client CPU) in setting up the encrypted connection for each HTTPS request.

Aside from any general info/advice, I'm curious about:

- As a very rough approximation, how much extra time does an HTTPS request take compared to HTTP? Assume content length of 1 byte and an average PC.
- Will every AJAX request after the first have anything significant cached, allowing it to establish the connection quicker? If so, how much quicker?

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in HTTPS is slower. Personal information shouldn't be cached, you have encryption on both ends, and an SSL handshake is relatively slow.

Long-polling will help. Long keep-alives are good. Enabling SSL sessions on your server will avoid a lot of the overhead as well.

The real trick is going to be doing load-balancing or any sort of legitimate caching. Not sure how much that will come into play in your system, being a chat server, but it's something to consider.

Comment: True. I've updated my answer a bit. Then comes the question of "can vs. should".

Answer (score 0):

You'll get more information from [this article](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html).

Most of the overhead is in the handshake (exchanging certificates, checking for their revocation, ...). Session resumption and the recent *false start* extension helps in that respect.
In my experience, the worse case scenario happens when using client-certificate authentication and advertising too many CAs ([the `CertificateRequest` message sent by the server can even become too big](http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=2599797)); this is quite rare since in practice, when you use client-certificate authentication, you would only accept client-certificates from a limited number of CAs.

If you configure your server properly (for resources for which it's appropriate), you can also enable browser caching for resources served over HTTPS, using `Cache-Control: public`.